# Implications if the inverse image of a measurable set has zero measure

Tags: measure-theory

I'm wondering about the following problem from measure theory. Suppose $f(x)=x^2$ and $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of the positive reals. Then if $\mu(f^{−1}(A))=0$ does this imply that $\mu(A)=0$?

Comment: I guess you also want $f$ to be surjective? Or else there are silly examples like $f(x) = \arctan(x)$, $A = [10,12]$. Also, do you want *strict* monotonicity? Or is this $x < y  \Rightarrow $f(x) \leq f(y)$?

Comment: Good point, I am actually interested in $f(x)=x^2$ on the positive reals.